# ImageJ (Fiji) How do I use multiple image processor on a folder of .LSM files to run the following commands?

Tags: image-processing, macros, imagej

I would like to use multiple image processor on a folder of .LSM files to disinterleave 2 channels, save only the first (the only one with data), and then run z-project to flatten the stack.  I want to run these operations:

```
run("Deinterleave", "how=1");
run("Z Project...", "projection=[Max Intensity]");
```

When I run this on a folder of .LSM files I get this error message:

```
"File is not in a supported format, a reader plugin is not available, 
or it was not found"  filename.lsm
```

The multiple image processor works on a folder full of .tiff files, so I assume it must be an .lsm problem?  Is there a fix?  I can open the files and carry out the operations manually.  I can also open an .LSM file and run a macro with these commands on it successfully.  Why can't I run it on the folder?